# Variable sharing between two sibling component in angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have 2 sibling component and I want to access one variable of one component to be accessed in another one. I used shared Services but it is not working. Can you please tell where am I wrong?

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService{
  private isSuccess = new Subject<boolean>();
  getSaveBtnStatus(){
    return this.isSuccess.asObservable();
  }
  setSaveBtnStatus(value: boolean){
    this.isSuccess.next(value);
  }
}
```

Component 1:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private myshared: SharedService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {    
  }

  login = (user) => {
    var username = user.username;
    var password = user.password;
    var user_api , user_birth ;
    var url = 'https://swapi.co/api/people/?search='+username;
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(data => { 
      var count = data.json().count;
      if( count == 0 )alert("NO such user");
    if( count > 0 ) {
      user_api= (data.json().results[0].name);
      user_birth = (data).json().results[0].birth_year;
      if( password == user_birth && username == user_api ) {
        console.log("Successful");
        this.myshared.setSaveBtnStatus(true);// using shared service
        this.router.navigate(['/search']);
     } else if ( password != user_birth || username != user_api) 
       alert("CHECK Your Username and Passowrd");
   }
  })
  }
}
```

Component 2:

```
export class SearchPlanetComponent implements OnInit {
  form;
  private loading: boolean = false;
  private results: Observable<Array<String>>;
  public searchField : FormControl
  private isSuccess :Boolean
  constructor(private myservice: SearchService,
    private myshared:SharedService, private http: Http) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myshared.getSaveBtnStatus().
      subscribe(
        data => console.log(data) // nothing is printed in console.
      );
}
```

please tell why the service function get/set is not working?

Comment: Can you please create a plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because when you emit value inside subject the underlying component was suppose to listen wasn't loaded. That component is getting loaded after `router.navigate` called.

You should consider using [**`BehaviorSubject`**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md) instead of `Subject`, as `BehaviourSubject` persist last emitted value. Also it emits `last/inital` persisted value when someone subscribes to it.

```
//it needs initial state while registering it, so passed false
private isSuccess = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```